# How can you search a UIViewController for number of UITextFields?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

More generally how do you search a UIViewDelegate for UI elements?

Right now, I'd like to count the number of UITextFields in my current view to populate the correct number of UILabels in other views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)textFieldCountInsideView:(UIView *)parentView
{
    NSInteger count = 0;
    for (UIView *subview in parentView.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            count = count + [self textFieldCountInsideView:subview];
    }
    return count;
}
```

And somewhere in your UIViewController:

```
NSInteger count = [self textFieldCountInsideView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the text fields are direct subviews of your current view, just loop through the current view's subviews, and test for whether they're UITextField class. If they're not all direct subviews, then you would need to drill down into all top level subviews to see if any of them also contained UITextFields.

Comment: Thanks for the help - they are all direct subviews so it shouldn't need any extra drilling. :)